# Add rel=lightbox to custom string

Tags: excerpt, thumbnails

I'm using the following code in my functions.php to show thumbnails in my excerpt:

```
function pietergoosen_kry_eerste_prentjie() {
global $post;
$first_img = '';
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

return $first_img;
}

function pietergoosen_kyk_url_bestaan($url) {
$headers = wp_get_http_headers($url);

if (!is_array($headers)) :
    return FALSE;
elseif (isset($headers["content-type"]) && (strpos($headers["content-type"],"image") !== false)) :
    return TRUE;
else :
    return FALSE;
endif;
}
function pietergoosen_verstel_prentjie_grootte($image, $alt, $newwidth, $newheight) {
if (!file_exists($image) && !pietergoosen_kyk_url_bestaan($image)) return '';
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
if (!$width || !$height) return '';

if ($newwidth) 
    $newheight = intval($newwidth/$width * $height);
else
    $newwidth = intval($newheight/$height * $width);
return '<img src="' . $image . '" width=' . $newwidth . ' height='. $newheight . ' alt=' . $alt . '/>';
}
```

I'm calling these functions into my content.php template just beneath the_excerpt like this:

```
<div class="alignleft">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
          <?php echo pietergoosen_verstel_prentjie_grootte(pietergoosen_kry_eerste_prentjie(), get_the_title(), 125, 0); ?>
       </a>
   </div>
```

What I now need to do is to add the rel="lightbox" attribute to the thumbnail displayed. Here is how I do it for all other images:

```
function pietergoosen_voeg_lightbox_rel_attribute_by_the_content($content) {
   global $post;
   $pattern ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'pietergoosen_voeg_lightbox_rel_attribute_by_the_content');
```

I can't get this method to work on the excerpt thumbnails. Any ideas on how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is what i dit at the end of the day, and it works fine.
I replaced:

```
<div class="alignleft">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <?php echo pietergoosen_verstel_prentjie_grootte(pietergoosen_kry_eerste_prentjie(), get_the_title(), 125, 0); ?>
   </a>
</div>
```

with:

```
<div class="alignleft">
        <a href="<?php echo pietergoosen_kry_eerste_prentjie() ?>" title="<?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="lightbox">
          <?php echo pietergoosen_verstel_prentjie_grootte(pietergoosen_kry_eerste_prentjie(), get_the_title(), 125, 0); ?>
       </a>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html output for the excerpt thumbnails it is difficult to say why your code is not working.

However I would also look into str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi Matt, here is my html: <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/pos-nommer-2/" title="Permalink to Pos nommer 2" rel="bookmark">
              <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/100_0387-300x225.jpg" width="125" height="93" alt="Pos" nommer="" 2="">           </a> I've just added the title and bookmark attributes.

Comment: An alternative solution would be:

    `function
pietergoosen_voeg_lightbox_rel_attribute_by_the_content($content) {
        global $post;

        $content = str_replace(' href', 'rel="lightbox" href', $content);
        return $content;
    }`